# unable to download pdf from this particular url using python

Tags: python

I have tried downloading a .pdf file using the following code but I can't open the downloaded file, it shows pdf error. I also tried doing the same with urllib2, requests none of them helped. Please help in resolving this.

```
import urllib
import os

pdf_link = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes/account/login?dest=%2Fr%2F23c59475ad19d393/pdf"
pdf_file = "sample.pdf"
response = urllib.urlopen(pdf_link)
file = open(pdf_file, 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: Open the downloaded PDF with an text editor and you will see an error message.

Comment: The URL on its own indicates that it is actually a login page and not a PDF. You will have to be authenticated first.

Comment: Ok, can you help in doing that?